# weblight Page not able to load all its components

Tags: javascript, java, web, web-scraping, googleweblight

I am having a web page which loads 400 `<div>` components when we load the page (normally).

The same web page ,when I am trying to load using weblight : ( 
 `http://weblight.in/?lite_url=<page url>`
)

it is loading only 180 `<div>` tags

why it is not able load remaining  components (it not even css or java-script components) ?

Because of that , I am not able scrap the elements in Jsoup using java

Comment: java != javascript, also why the extra tags?

Comment: @dave i am trying to scrap the data in java using jsoup ,so I used java tag, even i know the difference between java and javascript